# Keeping FTP Folder Constantly Up To Date Based On Local Folder

Tags: ftp

Does anybody know a decent freeware FTP utility, preferably that can run in the background, that can mirror a local folder, constantly checking the files there for changes, and then automatically refreshing the FTP folder when the local files change?

Comment: Sadly, my OS is Windows Vista

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on Server Fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interested in this as well. I know about the Rsync option of course, but would like to have a Windows option that does the same thing..

Answer (score 2):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) has a "keep remote directory up to date" feature under the commands tab which I use to do this. It first asks whether you want to sync the whole directory, then automatically uploads any file as soon as you save it. I'm currently looking for a similar solution for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone.  I ended up using the FastNet NMFTP component in Borland C++ Buidler 5 to write my own Windows Version of Sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a Linux or UNIX box you can use a shell script that periodically runs under cron to sync a folder to a "master" folder.  You could use rsync in that shell script to do the actual sync.

Is that helpful?

David Kerins